# GSon deserializing floats as 0.0

Tags: java, android, gson

Here is my object

```
{  
         "Id":12345,
         "some":1,
         "xCoord":248.0000,
         "yCoord":369.0000
}
```

For whatever reason the xVal and yVal are deserialized as “0.0”. How might I fix this? I need float.

My model is just a POJO

```
class MyClass{
  private int id;
  private int some;
  private double xCoord;//or float, neither works; I prefer float
  private double yCoord;
  ...//other fields
}
```

All other fields work fine, except the float or double xVal yVal

Also my Gson instance is

```
sGsonUpperCamelCase = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(typeFactory).create();
```

The `typeFactory` is not for this POJO but for some others, which all work fine. Anyway, everything is working fine with my entire system, except this one object's float/double fields.

Comment: can you post your model?

Comment: post your model class sample then we will get an idea where is the issue

Comment: deserialised into what, exactly? A bean?

Comment: I have updated to show my POJO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the method `setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)`.

With this policy, Gson expects the Json fields to be named `XCoord` and `YCoord`, starting with an uppercase letter. That means the Java field `xCoord` gets the value from the Json field `XCoord`, but since that does not exist, its value defaults to `0.0`.

So you have two options:

- Remove the `setFieldNamingPolicy()` if you don't need it anywhere. Although it looks like you rely on it with the field `id`.
- Rename the Json fields to `XCoord` and `YCoord`.